# Attempted to wrap sendRequest which is already wrapped

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I'm writing unit tests using Jasmine for my Backbone cache and am trying to mock up a function response using Sinon.js. For different tests, I expect different things to happen so I am creating a mock before each test and deleting it after, then filling in the `expects` behavior within the test itself. However, I'm getting an error and the tests are failing.

Here's my spec with just the relevant tests (other tests aren't using mock):

```js
describe("mysite.core.Cache.XFooInfo", function() {
    var fnMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        fnMock = sinon.mock(fn);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        delete fnMock;
    });

    it("should make a request after function fooCreated called", function() {
      fnMock.expects("sendRequest").once().withExactArgs("ModuleFoo", "getFoo", ["1000"]);

      events.trigger("fooCreated", [{Args:[test.data.XFooInfo]}]);
      fnMock.verify();
    });
 });
describe("mysite.core.Cache.XFooBarInfo", function() {
    var fnMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        fnMock = sinon.mock(fn);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        delete fnMock;
    });

    it("should make a request after function booUpdated called", function() {
      var booCopy = $.extend(true, {}, test.data.XBooInfo);

      booCopy[0].Args[0].FooID = "12345";
      fnMock.expects("sendRequest").once().withExactArgs("ModuleFoo", "getFoo", ["12345"]);

      events.trigger("booUpdated", booCopy);
      fnMock.verify();
    });
 });
```

The first test works fine and passes. The second test, however, gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap sendRequest which is already wrapped
    at Object.wrapMethod (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/sinon-1.7.1.js:528:23)
    at Object.expects (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/sinon-1.7.1.js:2092:27)
    at null.<anonymous> (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/shasta-cList-tests/spec/CacheSpec.js:909:15)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/jasmine-1.2.0.rc3/jasmine.js:1024:15)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/jasmine-1.2.0.rc3/jasmine.js:2025:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/jasmine-1.2.0.rc3/jasmine.js:1978:8)
    at jasmine.Spec.execute (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/jasmine-1.2.0.rc3/jasmine.js:2305:14)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/jasmine-1.2.0.rc3/jasmine.js:2025:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/jasmine-1.2.0.rc3/jasmine.js:1978:8)
    at jasmine.Suite.execute (https://localhost:8443/mysite/web/tests/libs/jasmine-1.2.0.rc3/jasmine.js:2450:14)
```

I can't find anything in the Sinon.js docs to tell me what I'm doing wrong. I know `verify` also does a `restore` on all the functions it mocks and I thought that it was enough to allow me to write a new `expects` behavior for the same function, but apparently I was wrong.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after spending 2 hours on this problem last Friday with no luck, I figured it out twenty min after posting this question. Adding `var fn.sendRequest = function(module, fnName, args) {};` to the `beforeEach` function fixed all the failing tests.

Comment: deleting variables is a weird thing to do in js, it's usually used to remove a member from an object, like delete myobj.arbitraryAttribute;

Also your comment has a syntax error, you can't say var fn.sendRequest = anything. Either you say var identifier = something; or fn.sendRequest = something.
So I think you've got a few issues with general js understanding. Generally if sinon is complaining that objects have already been wrapped then you need to call .restore() on the wrapped object, in your case at the end of each test.

Answer (score 0):

this one works too, less to type:

```
var fn.sendRequest = function () { };
```